# Reduce 2.503V regulated voltage by just about 3mV

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator, voltage-reference

I have a handful of REF192GP reference voltage sources. They are specified to produce a relatively precise 2.5V. Measuring each device I typically get a few mV higher than 2.5V, for example 2.503V. More generally, the datasheet specifies +-10mV for the "G Grade".

The reference voltage is used on one to eight (the number changes during operation) LM324 inputs, each having a 1MΩ pull-down resistor, so on the order of >= 100kΩ total load.

I would like to shave off just a few mV from that voltage so that I can get closer to the desired 2.5V. I am looking for a "clever" solution that is ideally simple to build with a few handy components (other than simply buying the more precise "F Grade" or "E Grade").

Example: A voltage divider on the order of a kΩ.
Pro: Adds around 2.5mA of load, which is comfortably below the 30mA specified in the datasheet.
Pro: The worst-case load of 100kΩ will drop the voltage only by a tiny fraction of a mV, which is more precise than I can measure anyways.
Contra: Potentiometers (even trim potentiometers) are difficult to set reliably to such extreme ratios.

Comment: There's not a lot of point I don't think; could you explain why you need to do this? The LM324 has a typical offset of 2-3 mV by itself, so you'll need to consider that as well. And also the input bias current...

Comment: What kind of resistance does your load have?

Comment: How are you measuring the voltage? WIthout a bit of care, your measurement accuracy is likely to be worse than the offset you are trying to get rid of.

Comment: The LM324 are part of the equipment under test. They are simple voltage followers feeding a 12-bit ADC (ADS7828). There are also a hand full of protection components, but only the 1MΩ pull-down-resistors are relevant for loading. The REF192GP I previously used always resulted in consistent (within 2 ADC digits) measurement results within our manufacturing tolerances (tested over thousands of devices). A new REF192GP outputs a slightly higher voltage, moving us slightly outside our tolerances.

Comment: @awjlogan The LM324's offset was not an issue previously.

Comment: @MissMulan As explained in the post, the REF192GP is loaded with one to eight LM324 inputs, each having a 1MΩ pull-down resistor. Is there anything more specific you need to know?

Comment: @YellowYeti The slightly increased voltage is noticable in the measurements.

Comment: @NikoO If the LM324 is a buffer, then it's adding 2 mV typical, uncharacterised for a particular component, but up to 5-7 mV (depending on manufacturer). I don't see why adding a fixed offset is an issue. More information on the why you think it is an issue would be helpful.

Comment: I have tested thousands of devices with a REF192GP that outputs 2.5V as exactly as my multimeter can measure it. The measurements done by the ADC are only rarely outside our tolerances (I won't go into the details of how the tolerances are decided) and when they are, it's only one channel. I swap the two LM324 of the device with each other and then the measurements are OK again. The new REF192GP outputs 2.503V according to my multimeter. This consistently places measurements outside our tolerances. So clearly the LM324 isn't the problem, the REF192GP is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this. The pot will be easy to set (range is only about 10mV). Output impedance is < 275 ohms. Adjust values if that's too high.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7dkuE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Of course if you happen to have a reference that is < 2.5V or an offset that is in the wrong direction this won't help.

Comment: I’m thinking voltage follower (low offset) opamp if the impedance is too high.

Comment: @winny  that’s certainly an option.

Comment: Great idea! Will test on monday. Since apparently almost all of the REF192GP are >= 2.5V, that will work fine for me.

Comment: @winny That would probably be more effort than I am willing to put into this.

Comment: Thank you!  

This configuration works and is simple enough to build. I had to change the resistor values, though, because with those high values, the output voltage drops by several mV depending on the number of connected LM324 inputs and 1MΩ pull-down-resistors. 500Ω potentiometer (didn't have a 1kΩ anyways), 25Ω instead of 100Ω and 6.8kΩ instead of 20kΩ. Now the output is stable barely within 1mV, which is good enough for me.  

Here is a little thingie that helped me decide the values: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ncdoxg0yg4